# js My goal is to make cards that are green when the correct guess is clicked and red if not clicked

Tags: javascript

is there any method to shorten this code?
I want to do it using the "onclick" method.
My goal is to make cards that are green when the correct guess is clicked and red if not clicked.
I know it's bad code ..
"Translate:google"

```js
var rest=document.getElementById("rest"),
k1=document.getElementById("k1"),
k2=document.getElementById("k2"),
k3=document.getElementById("k3"),
k4=document.getElementById("k4"),
k5=document.getElementById("k5"),
k6=document.getElementById("k6");
var ary=["k1","k2","k3","k4","k5","k6"];
function kart(){
    var R=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    if (ary[R]=="k1") {k1.onclick=function(){k1.style.backgroundColor="green";}}
    else{k1.onclick=function(){k1.style.backgroundColor="red";}}

            if (ary[R]=="k2") {k2.onclick=function(){k2.style.backgroundColor="green";}}
    else{k2.onclick=function(){k2.style.backgroundColor="red";}}

            if (ary[R]=="k3") {k3.onclick=function(){k3.style.backgroundColor="green";}}
    else{k3.onclick=function(){k3.style.backgroundColor="red";}}

            if (ary[R]=="k4") {k4.onclick=function(){k4.style.backgroundColor="green";}}
    else{k4.onclick=function(){k4.style.backgroundColor="red";}}

            if (ary[R]=="k5") {k5.onclick=function(){k5.style.backgroundColor="green";}}
    else{k5.onclick=function(){k5.style.backgroundColor="red";}}

            if (ary[R]=="k6") {k6.onclick=function(){k6.style.backgroundColor="green";}}
    else{k6.onclick=function(){k6.style.backgroundColor="red";}}

    
} 

function restle(){

    k1.style.backgroundColor="#000066";
    k2.style.backgroundColor="#000066";
    k3.style.backgroundColor="#000066";
    k4.style.backgroundColor="#000066";
    k5.style.backgroundColor="#000066";
    k6.style.backgroundColor="#000066";
    kart();
}
window.onload=function(){kart();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like a lot of that seems to be redundant code, of course without looking at the HTML I can't be too sure but you can rewrite it to look and feel less redundant. Also, it seems the way your program works is that you pick a random number, and based on that random number you assign 2 event listeners, which would mean that clicking on any of the other cards would do nothing. I am assuming what you want to do is have the user keep clicking cards until they find the correct one?

To remove redundancy I would change the HTML, so I am assuming you have 6 `<div>`s that each represent a card

```html
<div class="card" id="k1"></div>
<div class="card" id="k2"></div>
<div class="card" id="k3"></div>
<div class="card" id="k4"></div>
<div class="card" id="k5"></div>
<div class="card" id="k6"></div>
```

something simple like that, although yours may look different. I add the HTML so that I can loop through all of the div elements and apply the correct `onclick` listeners only to the element that needs it, instead of having to define it for each one, because like you said, you want a shorter code. We can get rid of a lot of things to shorten the code overall.

```js
//Let's get our random number first
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
//Grab all cards
var cards = document.querySelectorAll("div.card"); //This method retrieves an array of elements using their CSS selector
//Now we can loop through each card and only have to write the line of code once instead of redundantly 6 times!!!
cards.forEach(function (card) {
    //Now we wanted to set their background colors to "#000066"
    card.styles.backgroundColor = "#000066";
    //Add the onclick listener
    card.addEventListener("click", function () {
        //Then we check to see if it is the correct random number id, if it is we make the background color green, if not we make it red
        if (card.getAttribute("id") == "k" + String(randumNumber)) {
            card.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
        else {
            card.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    });
    
});
```

Comment: thank you so much.
I couldn't explain it correctly because of "google translate". your assumptions
 completely true. i see some codes new. ecmascript6 codes I guess. You have been very helpful.

Comment: I don't have any ES6 in there, the newest function in there is the `forEach` but that was added in ES5, if this is the correct answer could you mark it as so?